Identify movie/TV show with a guy pretending to be a god
A while ago I watched either a TV show or movie where one of the main character was considered a god but it turned out that he just had a lot of people working for him to set up scenarios he would appear to have god like powers.
The only scenario I can recall is battlefield one where he stands up against a number of men who all seemingly drop dead at the click of his fingers. He leaves one of them alive to go and tell the other what he saw. Once that guy has left a bunch of hidden people appear who had killed the men with bow and arrows from their hiding places.

Hi. Do you know the country\language? The approximate year of release?

You are discribing the beginning of Hercules 2014 (the one starring Dwayne Johnson to not confuse with The Legend of Hercules released also in 2014).
Hercules is a regular man, just stronger (it's Dwayne Johnson after all), but a simple human. He builds his reputation on doing extraordinary things, and for that, he has a team to cover up/him. That's how he builds the legend. It's like a magic show in other words.
The description from Wikipedia describes that:

Hercules is the leader of a band of mercenaries comprising the
  spear-wielding prophet Amphiaraus of Argos, the knife-throwing thief
  Autolycus of Sparta, the feral warrior Tydeus of Thebes, the Amazon
  archer Atalanta of Scythia and his nephew storyteller Iolaus of
  Athens. Hercules is said to be the demigod son of Zeus, who completed
  the legendary Twelve Labors, only to be betrayed by Hera who drove him
  insane and caused him to murder his wife Megara and their children
  during a visit to King Eurystheus. Throughout the film, it is not
  clearly established that Hercules is truly the son of Zeus, and many
  are skeptical of the claim as well as of the stories of Hercules'
  famous Twelve Labors.

The scene (starts at ~3:08)



